# Cannot deploy anchor program. Failing panicked at 'Must deploy: Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" }'

Tags: anchor

Trying to run: https://github.com/valentinmadrid/solana-squads-escrow

I run: `anchor build`, it completes.

But when I try deploy it, I get:

```
anchor deploy
Deploying cluster: https://api.devnet.solana.com
Upgrade authority: /Users/nikiv/solana/my-keypair.json
Deploying program "escrow"...
Program path: /Users/nikiv/src/go/try/sol-pay/solana-squads-escrow/target/deploy/escrow.so...
thread 'main' panicked at 'Must deploy: Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" }', cli/src/lib.rs:3124:18
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

What can I do to make the deploy work?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved after I renamed solana file wallet to `id.json`